# Assign API connection to variable in class and use across closures

Tags: php, api, class, closures

I want to use the $api variable that is assigned with an API connection:

```
$api = ApiFactory::create('Token_String');
```

across all closures inside a class:

```
class ApiConnection
{
   public static function getSampleData()
   {
      $api->getDataResource();
   }

   public static function getAnotherData()
   {
      $api->getAnotherResource();
   }
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class property and access with `self` or `static`:

```
class ApiConnection
{
   public static $api = null; //or private / protected

   public static function connect($token)
   {
      self::$api = ApiFactory::create($token);
   }
   public static function getSampleData()
   {
      if(!self::$api) { self::connect(); }
      self::$api->getDataResource();
   }
   public static function getAnotherData()
   {
      if(!self::$api) { self::connect(); }
      self::$api->getAnotherResource();
   }
}
```

Then:

```
ApiConnection::connect('Token_String'); //optional
ApiConnection::getSampleData();
```

Using an object:

```
class ApiConnection
{
   public $api = null; //or private / protected

   public function __construct($token)
   {
      $this->api = ApiFactory::create($token);
   }
   public function getSampleData()
   {
      $this->api->getDataResource();
   }
   public function getAnotherData()
   {
      $this->api->getAnotherResource();
   }
}
```

Then:

```
$A = new ApiConnection('Token_String');
$A->getSampleData();
```